# Collation Issue with Views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've created 2 views in a database.  Both have a collation of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  View 1 is querying data from a db with the same collation.  View 2 is querying data from a db with a collation of Latin1_General_CI_AS.  Even though the views show the same collation I'm running into an issue when I run the following query:

```
Select
  V1.ID,
  V1.Amount
From V1
Where V1.ID NOT IN 
    (Select V2.ID
     From V2)
```

This returns the following error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS"
>   and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I've attempted to add "COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" to the end of the Where statement without success.  I've also tried changing the collation at the field level in the select statement without success.

How can I compare this data with mismatched collation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an explicit collation wherever you're comparing strings between databases, like so:

```
Select
  V1.ID,
  V1.Amount
From V1
Where V1.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT IN 
    (Select V2.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
     From V2)
```

The "DATABASE_DEFAULT" will basically cast the string to the collation of the database you're running the view from. Both collations will match, and the comparison will succeed without error.

Note this same technique is useful for declaring temp table varchar and nvarchar columns and doing joins with temp tables, where the collation of the database may differ from the collation of the installed SQL Server (and thus the collation of tempdb).